# Spring Reactive Router Path - Wildcard with exclusion

Tags: java, spring, glob

I have a Spring Reactive app which serves up a single page React app.

To serve the React pages, I have a wildcard path of `/**`. This largely works, except for one case.

The non-React endpoints I want my Spring app to handle are all prefixed with `/api`.

Right now, if I call an `/api` endpoint that doesn't exist, it gets handled by the React endpoint (`/**`) and so it serves up the `index.html` for React and a 200 instead of a 404 like I want.

According to the documentation, it looks like Spring Reactive Router supports glob patterns, but I tried the pattern `/!(api)/**` which seems like it should work according to glob testers. However, this causes all calls that should have gone to that endpoint to 404.

Any ideas on a wildcard pattern to catch everything except endpoints that start with `/api`?

Comment: Why not a /api/**  fallback that serves a 404?

Comment: I thought about doing that and may have to go with that ultimately, but it feels a little weird to create an endpoint just to 404, since normally non-existent endpoints will do that on their own.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like according to the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates) you can only use limited a subset {*, **, ?} of glob. You probably need to add some prefix to the react as well, which would give you a proper separation.

Comment: If I added a prefix to the React part it would give me ugly looking public URLs as they would all have a random extra prefix for no reason (from the users' perspective).